# Which technologys are used for a page like this and how can i detect them?

Tags: templates, frameworks, content-management-system, html

I've been learning WebDev for 1 year now and I'm really interested in learning new things. This time I checked: [Nexusmods](https://www.nexusmods.com), a site where modding of popular games is the topic at all. I've been trying to figure out how to make this website, what technologies are being used, can not even find a used CMS?
Is there a techology unknown to me? Or do you create tons of pages for each new incoming mod with plain HTML?
I am sure there is a Template technology in use, but what kind of?

I am very interested in how to find out on what kind of technology such an extensive website was built.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a browser extension to identify what technologies are being used on a webpage. For example: [Wappalyzer](https://www.wappalyzer.com/).

Comment: thanks @Iosu, i did this already. IMHO there must exist a template tech.